# Best way to filter unseen videos in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

We build a video-section for our users. The user can filter the videos by rating/views/date.
Also the user can decide to hide already seen videos. This is where i struggle a little bit.

right now i have a solution, which is working, but doesnt seem to perform great.

```
if @filter == "newest"
  if @unseen
    ids = Videothek::Video.where(videothek_category_id: categories).pluck(:id)
    views = Videothek::Video::View.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:video_id)
    unseen = ids - views #ids der ungesehenen videos
    @videos = Videothek::Video.where(id: unseen).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @videos = Videothek::Video.where(videothek_category_id: categories).order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

i thought it must be possible to do with a scope, like `Videothek::Video.unseen(current_user).order(.....)`

A `Video` has_many `Views`, but i struggle to get the join running, as i just want the videos, that DONT have an association with an videothek_video_view, where user_id = 1 (or current_user.id).

can somebody help me out?

btw: we are on RoR3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use where.not(video_id: [ids]) to make database filter videos user already seen. This method is added since rails 4.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot

instead of pluck(:id) you may use .ids. I would also move the code somewhere out of controller.

Probably you question would fit better to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since you already have working version.

Comment: sorry, forgot to say, we are on rails 3.

Comment: so would you say, it is the right way, to get a list of ALL viewed videos, and then subtact them from the result?

Comment: so then i run a scope `Videothek::Video::View.where(user_id: user.id).pluck(:video_id)` and use in scope the where  `where("id NOT IN(#{seen.join(',')})")
` which gives me then 

`=> "SELECT `videothek_videos.* FROM`videothek_videos  WHERE (id NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5,25,26,27,29))"`

first look: working. second look: SQL might get huuuuuuuge (after 4.000 video views? ), ain't a problem for my mysql?

Comment: No it's definitely the bad way. When you hit too many videos there is possible perfomance issues. Sorry i do not have RoR3 experience, but afaik they are very similar in active record methods. So, hmm, you may try to use something like `Videothek::Video.includes(:videothek_views).references(:videothek_views).where('videothek_views.user_id != ?', current_user.id)`. I am not sure if this will work in RoR3 but i think it should. Check if the generated query is correct and fix it if need. You may also want restrict select to only Video table if you dont need any information from views.

Comment: .references came with 4.0 - yup, oldschool 3.2 sucks. lets see, if it kills the performance, we just deacitvate the future. no fun at all...

Comment: You may replace references with joins and check what query it generates. Technically it should do the same query, but i'm not sql/AR expert. oldschool is not sucks it just has less syntax sugar :) I would also suggest to use something like Redis. I am not sure how exactly it may be implemented in your case, but it definitely can.

Comment: yup, we are using redis already and propably we'll save the views into it. ill give you a correct answer since you helped me with the scope :)